# QML dir not in release

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qmake

I have a project structure like this:

```
project
-project.pro (subdirs)
|-app
| |-app.pro (app)
| |-QML
| |-CPP
| |-ICONS
|
|-lib
  |-lib.pro (subdirs, copied from qtvirtualkeyboard/src)
  |-config.pri (copied from qtvirtualkeyboard/src)
  |-virtualkeyboard
    |-...
```

Where the `lib`-dir is equal to the [qtvirtualkeyboard/src](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard.git/tree/src) with just the dir and project renamed from *src* to *lib*.

Now everything runs fine when I click on run in *QtCreator*
But as I'd like to deploy it with `windeployqt` the problem is that the `QML`-dir is not copied into the `release`-dir.

When I deploy it (with `make install` followed by the `windeployqt`), I get the file structure:

```
project
|-.moc
|-.obj
|-.pch
|-.rcc
|-debug
|-QML <-- This should not be here, but a subdir of release
|-release
  |-app.exe
  |-...otherstuff
```

I think it might be (my fault) the fault of the `.qmake.conf`, which I do not understand and copied from the `qtvirtualkeyboard`

**.qmake.conf:**

```
load(qt_build_config)
MODULE_VERSION = 5.8.1
```

**.qmake.stash:**

```
QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS = \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/include \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/include-fixed \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++ \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32 \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward
QMAKE_DEFAULT_LIBDIRS = \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0 \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/lib/gcc \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib \
    D:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/lib
```

Or of on of the projectfiles, where the one of the `lib.pro` was directly copied from the repository, and the `app.pro` on itself was running fine, before I relocated it as a subproject of `project.pro`.

**(EDIT) app.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11 \
          disable-desktop

SOURCES += main.cpp \
           ...

RESOURCES += \
    ICONS\ICONS.qrc

QML_IMPORT_PATH =

include(deployment.pri)

DISTFILES += \
    QML/...
    ...

HEADERS += \
    CPP/...
    ...

qmlsrc.files = QML/*
qmlsrc.path = $$OUT_PWD/QML

INSTALLS += qmlsrc
```

How could I fix that, besids adding a *custom deployment step* to copy the QML-dir? Following the answer of *@KevinKrammer*, I conclude the problem lies within: `qmlsrc.path = $$OUT_PWD/QML`. `OUT_PWD` contains the path where the Makefile is  generated. This is right, if I only run `app.pro`, but when I run `project.pro` it should be equivalent to `$$OUT_PWD/[debug,relase,...]/QML` so `$$PATH_TO_THE_EXE/QML`
Is there a way to write that somehow that generically, that it works in both cases: When I run `project.pro` and when I run `app.pro` and in both, `release` and `debug`, mode?

Comment: i've edited my answer to suggest options for debug/release difference handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify files, even using wildcard patterns, as [additional](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#installing-files) install targets, something along the lines of

```
qmlfiles.files = QML/*
qmlfiles.path = $$OUT_PWD/QML

INSTALLS += qmlfiles
```

debug/release differences can be handles in two ways

```
debug:qmlfiles.path = $$OUT_PWD/debug/QML
release:qmlfiles.path = $$OUT_PWD/release/QML
```

or

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    qmlfiles.path = ...
} else {
    qmlfiles.path = ...
}
```